# crystal report text object in details section

Tags: crystal-reports

i want report to get printed like this in **details section**:

```
 [textObject]                      [textObject]  (1) database field [textObject]
 [textObject]                      [textObject]  (2) database field [textObject]   
 [textObject]                      [textObject]  (3) database field [textObject]
```

But it is finally printing like follows:

```
[textObject]                       [textObject](1)                  [textObject]
[textObject]                       [textObject](2) <database field> [textObject]
[textObject]                       [textObject](3) <database field> [textObject]
[textObject]                       [textObject](4) <database field> [textObject]
```

It seems it is printing one extra line without database record.
It is an application letter which combines lot of text objects with database field in between.
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on textfield and select properties and select suppress if blank. Hope this will work

Beside suppress option you will see formula button. Click it and write formula as

if database field name = null

Let me know if it helps

Comment: What are those? Didnt you find suppress on blank?

Comment: no , right click>Format object>, there is no option like this

Comment: Also are you getting blank values from database?

Comment: visual studio 2010>CR>13-0-5 No no blank value i have double checked in query window

Comment: Can you see formula beside suppress option?

Comment: Write formula  if database field name = null

Comment: somehow i dont have crystal report with me otherwise could have easily told you. Also its been almost 6 yrs i have not worked on it. Have updated answer too

Comment: Formula : "if {bl.BL_NAME}="null" then false" it worked, thanks a million @AsfReva,u r still updated after 6yrs man.